# how to generate schema without column info (I just want the column names) using DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader

Tags: perl, dbix-class

I want to use `DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader` to generate the schema from Oracle database.
My code is below. My question is how to generate the schema without column info .
I just want the column names.

```
#============== generate code =================
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;

use DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader qw/ make_schema_at /;
make_schema_at(
    'My::Schema',
    { debug => 1,
        skip_relationships => 1,
        skip_load_external  => 1,
      dump_directory => './lib',
      constraint => qr/\ATF_F_.*\z/,
      generate_pod => '0',
    },
    [ 'dbi:Oracle:test', 'test', 'test',
    ],
);


#========= result TfFUser.pm=================
use warnings;

use base 'DBIx::Class::Core';
__PACKAGE__->table("TF_F_USER");
__PACKAGE__->add_columns(
  "partition_id",
  {
    data_type => "numeric",
    is_nullable => 0,
    original => { data_type => "number" },
    size => [4, 0],
  },
```

The result I want is just

```
use warnings;

use base 'DBIx::Class::Core';
__PACKAGE__->table("TF_F_USER");
__PACKAGE__->add_columns( "partition_id", column1, column2, ...
```

I don't want the column info such as

```
  {
    data_type => "numeric",
    is_nullable => 0,
    original => { data_type => "number" },
    size => [4, 0],
  }
```

Comment: I don't understand what problem the additional information is causing you. Can you give us some background to your question please?

Comment: sorry. the result i want is just the column name:
__PACKAGE__->add_columns( "partition_id",column1,column2....blabla); I dont want the column info  such as {
    data_type => "numeric",
    is_nullable => 0,
    original => { data_type => "number" },
    size => [4, 0],
  }, @Borodin

Comment: Please [*edit your question*](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36101277/edit) to provide information like that. I've done it for you this time. And yes, I understand what you're asking for, but I'm wondering what harm the additional column information is doing. Can't you just ignore it? It's not using a significant amount of space

Comment: Just a guess, but are you trying to use the Schema with SQLite and are afraid the additional info is going to make deploying there fail? DBIC will take care of that for you.

Answer (score 1):

Without any more information I'm going to have to say the answer is that you can't do that. I've looked at the source in `DBIx/Class/Schema/Loader/Base.pm` and there's no option for disabling output of the column information, although of course it's trivial to do either by hand or automatically

If you could have explained more about *why* you want to do this then I am sure we could have helped you